# C++: Issue Creating New Instance of Class After Current Instance Destroyed

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, instance

I am working on a Binary Search Tree (BST) program. Per the assignment's requirements, the user loads a text file to construct the tree. If the user would like, they can then create a new tree by loading a new text file. Loading a new text file should destroy the old tree.

To accommodate this require, my method to create a new tree, `readNewFile()`, first checks if a tree already exists. If it does, it runs the destructor on the tree. However, I then need to create a new tree, that exists outside the scope of `readNewFile()`, so that it can be accessed globally. Is this possible to do? If so, could you please explain how?

My reduced code:

```
int main() {

    //BST
    BST rootTree;

    readNewFile(rootTree);
    readNewFile(rootTree);

    return 0;
}


void readNewFile(BST& tree) {
    ifstream inFile;
    string fileName;

    // if tree was previously filled, destroy it
    if (tree.rootPtr() != NULL) {
        tree.~BST();
        BST tree = new BST();
    }

    cout << "\nEnter file to load: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, fileName);
    cout << "Opening file " << fileName << endl;
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    // Populates tree... //

}
```

Destructor (within BST.hpp):

```
BST::~BST() {
    destroyTree(root);
}

void BST::destroyTree(TreeNode*& treePtr) {
    if (treePtr != NULL) {
        destroyTree(treePtr->leftChildPtr);
        destroyTree(treePtr->rightChildPtr);
        delete treePtr;
    }
}
```

This returns a segfault, which makes sense, since the tree was destroyed. However, is there a way I can create a new tree, with the same scope as the destroyed `BST rootTree`?

Comment: can you please show what you are doing in the destructor?

Comment: Directly calling the destructor is generally not a good idea. Instead create a "clear" function, and call that from the destructor if needed.

Comment: As for your problem, have you used a debugger to find the location of the crash?

Comment: @yasouser - Not a problem, I've added the destructor. Let me know if it's a sufficient amount of code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That makes sense, but I think the instructor wants us to completely remove the previous instance.

Comment: @Adam_G: Remove `delete treePtr;` from `destroyTree()` and add it to `~BST()`. Like I said in my answer, call `destroyTree()` instead of calling the destructor directly (which by the way is not the correct way to delete an object).

Comment: @yasouser If I do that, though, then how does `destroyTree()` do anything? With the way it works now, it recursively deletes everything. If I take out `delete treePtr;`, won't it not delete anything?

Comment: "If I take out delete treePtr;, won't it not delete anything?" -- It will delete every node in the tree except the root pointer. When all is said and done and the BST object goes out of scope, the destructor gets called and it deletes the nodes and the root pointer. At this point, you don't want that to linger around.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish the requirement is to have a method called `del()` in your `BST` class. All it does is delete all the nodes of the tree but not the root pointer. This is the pointer that points to the root node. After calling `del()`, you can start creating a new tree. The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
// if tree was previously filled, destroy it
if (tree.rootPtr() != NULL) {
   tree.del()
}

// read the input file
// Start inserting the new nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

First off: what's wrong with the code.

As you already pointed out, if the tree is destroyed, you can't be using it again.  In this case, it's double-bad: by calling the destructor on `BST` in `readNewFile()`, you're causing the destructor to be called twice -- once when you explicitly call it, and the second time when the local instance in `main()` goes out of scope.  [This is bad.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dont-call-dtor-on-local.html)

---

Now about how to fix it:

The easiest way would just to declare `rootTree` as a pointer inside `main()`, and then make `readNewFile()` take a pointer-to-pointer as an argument.  `readNewFile()` would destroy the existing tree pointed to by the pointer, and then reset the pointer to point at the new tree it creates.  Simple.

What would be a better design, though, would be to make `readNewFile()` a member function of `BST`.  Then `main()` should construct a new `BST` and call that instance's `readNewFile()`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will play around with this idea.

Comment: @sheu: "What would be a better design, though, would be to make readNewFile() a member function of BST." --- I would advice against this simply because reading a file to create a BST is not an operation that you do on a binary search tree. This is completely external to it. Having a method like `readNewFile()` or `CreateBSTFromFile()` is something I would recommend.

Comment: @yasouser And you'd recommend these be in `main`, not as part of `BST`, right?

Comment: @yasouser: presumably you'd be touching the BST's internal node pointers and such.  To allow an external function to access and mutate these, you'd either have to make the members public, or provide the whole stack of getters and setters -- both of which would break encapsulation on `BST`.

So no, constructing a `BST` from file is not a completely external operation.

Comment: What you have right now is fine i/e doing the reading of the file and creating the BST in a separate function and calling it from main(). Instead of creating the file inside this function you can create it as part of main() and pass it as a parameter to this function. This function takes 2 parameters: one is the reference to the file to read from and the other is a reference to the BST object.

Comment: To expand on the encapsulation a bit more -- ideally, any users of `BST` should know only as much about `BST`'s internals as necessary to use it.  I presume you have the usual interface to a binary search tree in the `BST` class's prototype -- `insert()`, `erase()`, `find()`, etc.  It's a clearly defined interface that requires that users know nothing (and can know nothing) about how the `BST` is internally represented.  Similarly, a `createFromStream(std::istream& input)` to do the `readNewFile` bit would hide the internals from creators of `BST`s -- but that's a bit complicated for now.

Comment: Thanks guys. This has given me a lot to think about. Now I need to let it settle in overnight.

Answer (score 0):

You never invoke the destructor directly unless you know pretty well what you're doing. And then, it's typically because it was created using placement new. Further, "T t = new T;" doesn't make sense, assigning a pointer-to-T to a T. My guess is you are reproducing a Javaism here, but the object models of these two languages are too different.